# issue with DateTime.ToOADate()

Tags: c#, datetime

there's something i couldn't understand with DateTime.ToOaDate().

here's what i have

```
var plainDate = "01/07/2011";
var dateTime1 = DateTime.Parse(plainDate, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
var value = dateTime1.ToOADate();
var dateTime2 = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.FromOADate(value).ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

dateTime1 and dateTime2 should be the same, right? i only converted plain date into ticks and then recovered it as DateTime with the same culture,, but actually when i run it dateTime2 has the value of (7-Jan-2011) instead of (1-Jul-2011)

Comment: This has nothing to do with `ToOADate()`. Remove the `value` line and just use `DateTime.Parse(dateTime1.ToString(), new CultureInfo(...))` and you'll see exactly the same effect. It's the string conversions which are causing the problem, not `ToOADate` and `FromOADate`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because your call to ToString does not specify the culture info.

Try `ToString(new CultureInfo("en-GB"))` as well.

Answer (score 5):

When you do `DateTime.Parse`, you are specifying the format you expect the incoming date to be in.

When you do `ToString()`, you are specifying that the current culture should be used to format the date.

Here, I guess your `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat` is returning a US format. Hence, `DateTime.FromOADate(value).ToString()` returns `07/01/2011`, when you then parse this using en-GB, it returns the 7th of January.